# Are there any "gotchas" with this approach to handling errors in PHP?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I'm a relative newbie to PHP, but it seems to me that PHP's error handling is a bit of a ghetto, with errors and warnings interspersed with exceptions (and don't get me started on `die()`). As such, I'm not certain how best to go about creating, interpreting, and handling all error cases in my application.

My general plan of attack is roughly as follows:

1. Convert all warnings/errors into Exceptions, using `set_error_handler()` to wrap the errors as they come.
2. Code defensively, preemptively checking for things I expect to go wrong. Throw exceptions only when I can't handle the error directly. Usual `try/catch` blocks will be in place when needed, to handle exceptions I don't throw myself.
3. Wrap my entire application (i.e. my `index.php` point-of-entry file) in it's own `try/catch`. Should that fail, I'll throw an `HTTP 500` and show a suitable error page. Presumably this page will be a single, pre-compiled file rather than a collection of header/body/footer includes - this is largely so that I can still cover weird exceptions like a garbled template file. I assume this is why Google's 500-class error page looks so much different from everything else they put out.
4. As a corollary to #2 and #3, since I'm expecting to handle everything upfront, if I decide to throw my own exception, I'm also expecting *not* to catch the error, and instead let it bubble all the way up to my top level handler. The thinking here is that if I can't handle it when it happens, I'm probably ill-equipped to handle it anywhere else. I'm thinking of giving these errors their own subclass - perhaps `CriticalErrorException` - that can be identified directly in my logs/spawn an email so I can look into it quickly. In general, I'm expecting these to be things that *may* happen in dev, but should be ironed out by production.
5. Any error that makes it to the top gets logged in the database, with failover to a log file. Critical errors, as indicated above, trigger an email. If the reporting fails over to the file - i.e. there's a DB error - that would also trigger an email.

I think this covers most cases pretty well, but as I said I'm very new to PHP so I don't know if there are corner cases or weird behaviours that I'm overlooking.

What are the flaws in my plan? How can I overcome them?

Comment: That's a solid approach, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the strategy of letting unexpected exceptions bubble up to a top `catch` block and then serve out a `HTTP 500` is fine (many frameworks do just that).

I don't quite agree with making a `CriticalErrorException` -- maybe you don't expect to catch something now, but you might expand your error handling in the future (possibly in the face of additional application requirements). Just throw whatever is natural. A simple `Exception` is fine in most cases.

Regarding PHP errors: you do not strictly need to convert `E_ERROR` into an exception (it will kill your app anyway, and will show up in the error log as well). You would do well to handle `E_NOTICE` though, as notices almost always mean that there's something not right with the code.

Finally, when talking about PHP functions that raise warnings, I would go with this:

```
// Assume that php_function() raises E_WARNING and returns FALSE on error
// WARNING: if you have defined a custom error handler, IT WILL STILL BE CALLED
//          even though the @ operator suppresses the error
$result = @php_function($argument); // suppress error
if (!$result) {
    // error handling here
}
```

instead of this:

```
try {
    $result = php_function($argument);
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    // error handling here
}
```

The reason being that converting to an exception doesn't really buy you anything when you intend to react to the error immediately. On the contrary, the first code snippet will "tell" a developer reading it to look up the documentation for `php_function` if more info on its error handling strategy is needed. The second code snippet will require the developer to have knowledge about error handling specifically as implemented in your app.

**Update:**

I 'm not saying that you should use `@` to just ignore errors coming out of function calls. What I am saying is that, when using legacy PHP functions that behave this way, and when you are fully prepared to handle the error and recover from it, then of course it should no longer be considered an "error" regarding your application's execution. *In this specific case*, I recommend suppressing it so that it doesn't get reported as well.

Comment: your  @php_function($argument); is just terrible. @ has nothing to do here. And you are messing up error handling with error reporting here. While it's different matters. An error should be reported always, *regardless* of handling.

Comment: Any arguments other than "I don't like it"?

Comment: So, a) I can't catch E_ERROR no matter what; it'll just kill my application where it is and will be unhandleable (are these things like syntax errors that should be caught before prod, or do they sometimes show up unexpectedly?), and b) Should I not wrap everything in an exception in a custom error handler function in case I want to use `@` suppression? What's a "good" way to write the custom error handler in general?

Comment: Allow me to disagree. `@` has *everything* to do here. It says that you are expecting an error, and you do not want it to be reported because you are prepared to handle it if it occurs. Have you ever needed to write production code using functions like `getimagesize`?

Comment: Is there any way to indicate to the custom handler that you suppressed the error, or does PHP just call your handler and let the consequences fall as they may?

Comment: Only a fool would **expect** an error from properly running code. All expected errors should be properly handled **before**. getimagesize is an exceptional case, blame PHP authors for this. Error messages being used for debugging purpose and priceless for that. And you are throwing that tresaure into waste. Just because you misplace it.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: "E_ERROR: Fatal run-time errors. These indicate errors that can not be recovered from, such as a memory allocation problem. Execution of the script is halted". So, yes it will kill and yes it is unhandleable. It can occur expectedly (syntax error) or unexpectedly (out of memory). You should use exceptions in the app; just do not wrap *everything* in try/catch (overdoing something is also bad).

Comment: I didn't say anything about wrapping *everything* in a try/catch, just the things that need it. Do exceptions trigger the custom handler too, or is that just for errors? And if the custom handler is called even with `@` supression, like in your warning in your code, then is there any way for me to indicate to the handler, "don't worry about that error; i got this"

Comment: @Shrapnel: I would very much like to see your code that supposedly checks **all** conditions that may make e.g. `getimagesize` raise a warning beforehand. I would also like to see the code that makes sure it won't get get an error while reading, in which case it will raise E_NOTICE. As for "expecting" an error, please have the good faith to recognize that I meant "expecting" as in "being ready to handle it". Finally, I try to provide working solutions instead of blaming other people for whatever problems I need to face.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: exceptions don't trigger the custom error handler. To check if "you got this" from within the error handler, use `error_reporting()` (read **carefully** here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). To handle uncaught exceptions, you can use `set_exception_handler`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

Comment: I just read that page.. @suppression apparently sets `error_reporting()` to `0`, so I could have the custom handler just ignore anything with `error_reporting() == 0`, right?

Comment: You cannot be "fully prepared to handle the error". Just because there is not only one error. In case of filesystem operations there are dozens of them. Go guess, which one made your app unusable. You are still mixing up error handling with error reporting. Only one error it's from the program flow point of view and you have to *handle* this error. But frhom the debugging point of view there can be numerous errors, and you have to log them all. To sort things out later

Comment: @Sharpnel: I don't need to know which one error caused the E_WARNING. **You** would need to know that to *prevent* the error. I only need to know that "the file can't be read", which I hope you understand is a long way from making the app unusable. Finally, error handling **is already mixed with reporting** when you have defined a custom error handler, as the OP wants to do.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: Yep. But to clarify, `error_reporting` is set to 0 only *temporarily*.

Comment: @Jon: Yeah, I got that. It seems like the @ operator is shorthand for `$error_reporting = error_reporting(); executeLineOfCode; error_reporting($error_reporting);`